# replace("\"", "&ldquo;") method alternative using jstl

Tags: java, jsp, replace, jstl

I used before `myString.replace("\"", "&ldquo;")` in my jsp page. But I want to write this code using jstl. How to write that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to add for the benefit of any new visitors that you'll need to import the corresponding `functions` tag library as well. The `taglib` directive in your JSP should look like

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```

Then invoke the `replace()` function as before.

```
<p>Your branch's bank name is
    <c:out value="${fn:replace(branch.bank_name, '\"', '&ldquo;')}" />
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

`${fn:replace(branch.bank_name, '\"', '&ldquo;')}` I found answer to my question